# How to make the legend border tighter?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am trying to make the legend border tighter. What is the `\begin{axis}[legend style={...}]` property to adjust the legend border (both width and height of the border)?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel={XLABEL},
        ylabel={YLABEL},
        legend columns=-1]
        \addplot+[mark=none] plot {x^2};
        \addlegendentry{a}
        \addplot+[mark=none] plot {1};
        \addlegendentry{b}
        \addplot+[mark=none] plot {x};
        \addlegendentry{c}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the legend style options, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel={XLABEL},
        ylabel={YLABEL},
        legend style={inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=0pt},
        legend columns=-1]
        \addplot+[mark=none] plot {x^2};
        \addlegendentry{a}
        \addplot+[mark=none] plot {1};
        \addlegendentry{b}
        \addplot+[mark=none] plot {x};
        \addlegendentry{c}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tighter Legend Border]